# Converting particular date format in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a specific date conversion in R. I haven't found a solution to this particular conversion:

```
Sep 17, 2012
```

needs to be converted to:

```
2012-09-17
```

I am trying:

```
as.Date('Sep 17, 2012')
```

and:

```
as.Date(format('Sep 17, 2012', "%b %e, %Y")
```

Comment: You need to specify the format in `as.Date`: `as.Date("Sep 17, 2012", "%b %e, %Y")`.

Comment: awesome!! thank you.  Add as answer and I'll check it off

Comment: Glad to help, and will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the format of the date in `as.Date`:

```
as.Date("Sep 17, 2012", "%b %e, %Y")
# [1] "2012-09-17"
```